# Understanding proof of infinite subset of compact set must have limit point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I'm going through the following proof in Baby Rudin:

> **2.37 Theorem:** If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in K.
>
> **Proof:** If no point of $K$ were a limit point of $E$, then each $q\in K$ would have a neighborhood $V_q$ which contains at most one point of $E$ (namely, $q$ if $q\in{E}$). It is clear that no finite subcollection of ${V_q}$ can cover $E$; and the same is true of $K$, since $E\subset K$. This contradicts the compactness of $K$.

and I'm having trouble understanding why it is so clear that no finite subcollection of $V_q$ can cover $E$. Is this because $E$ is infinite? If so, can't this be extended to $K$ as well, for any finite subcollection of any open cover, completely irrespective of considering $E$, since $K$ is then also infinite? In particular, if we have some open cover $\Omega$ of $K$, then a finite subcollection $\Phi$ can't possibly cover $K$ since it is infinite. Hence, $K$ (or any infinite set) cannot be compact. Now my thinking is that this is bogus since the finite subcollection could be of infinite sets which do cover $K$, so in fact $K$ can be compact in this way (correct me if I'm wrong), but then this removes the argument for why $V_q$ cannot cover $E$ is obvious, since then the same logic could be applied. Also, this reasoning completely neglects any fact of limit points which were established, so I think if this was the reason then the theorem would be weak, which I'm assuming just isn't the case. So I'm thinking the reason must somehow involve the nonexistence of a limit point in $E$ assumed, but I can't seem to figure out what the reasoning is. Any insights on these points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part is that, by construction, each of the sets $V_q$ contains at most one point of $E$:

Since $E$ is an infinite subset of $K$, and since each $V_q$ contains at most one point from $E$, any finite subcollection of the sets $V_q$ will only cover a finite part of $E$. In other words, there does not exist a finite subcollection of the sets $V_q$ that cover all of $E$, and since $E\subseteq K$, no finite subcollection can cover $K$.

Comment: I see, so it's the fact that we are taking a finite subcollection **along** with the fact that $V_q\cap E$ is at most a singleton that lets use conclude this. And am I correct in my understanding that there could be a finite subcollection of _infinite_ subsets which covers $K$ (if we don't assume that infinite subsets don't have limit points of course)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that it is taking the finite subcollection along with $V_q\cap E$ being at most a singleton that gives us the contradiction. In fact, we only need each $V_q\cap E$ to be finite in order to conclude that no finite subcollection of them can cover the infinite set $E$. And yes, if $E$ (and thereby $K$) is infinite, then any cover by a finite subcollection of sets would have to contain at least one infinite set.